# Python: for statement behavior

Tags: python, syntax

My question concerns the output of this statement:

```
for x in range(4), y in range(4):
    print x
    print y
```

Results in:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
2
True
2
```

It seems there is a comparison involved, I just can't figure out why the output is structured like this.

Comment: Is this the actual code? Mine fails on the `for` with `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to write nested loops?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @Marcelo: y was initialised earlier as I failed to notice. See answers below.          

@S.Lott: No tutorial. Just noticed this while trying to find a short form for a loop over two variables...

Comment: Perhaps you should find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you're running this from an interactive console, and already had `y` defined with a value of 2 (otherwise, you'd get `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`). That would lead to the output you observed.

This is due to `for x in range(4), y in range(4):` actually being equivalent to the following when evaluated:

```
for x in (range(4), y in range(4)):
```

which reduces to...

```
for x in ([0,1,2,3], 2 in range(4)):
```

which again reduces to...

```
for x in ([0,1,2,3], True):
```

This then results in 2 iterations of the `for` loop, since it iterates over each element of the tuple:

1. `x = [0,1,2,3]`
2. `x = True`.

(And of course, `y` is still 2.)

Comment: Thanks for this in depth analysis

Answer (score 3):

You've created a weird, weird thing there.

```
>>> y = 2
>>> range(4), y in range(4)
([0, 1, 2, 3], True)
```

The `y in range(4)` is a membership test.

The `range(4), y in range(4)` is a pair of items; a tuple.

The variable `x` is set to range(4), then the result of `y in range(4)`.

The variable `y` is just laying around with a value; it is not set by the `for` statement.

This only works hacking around on the command line typing random stuff with `y` left laying around.

This isn't sensible Python code at all.

*[And yes, the word `in` has two meanings.  So do `()`'s and several other pieces of syntax.]*

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be used in any script I was just wondering what happens here

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have `y` defined prior to running this code. What you're iterating over is a two-item tuple: first item is `range`-generated list, second is `True`, which is result of the `y in range(4)`:

```
>>> y = 2
>>> for x in range(4), y in range(4):
    print x, 'x'
    print y, 'y'


[0, 1, 2, 3] x
2 y
True x
2 y
```

What I suspect you were trying to do is to iterate over two variables from two lists. Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library.html#zip) for this.

Comment: Ok seems I initialised the y some lines up. I didn't notice that

Comment: @BandGap: then you'd get a `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`. So I'm pretty sure it is initialised.

Comment: @BandGap, how about testing that with another print prior to running the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Dav nailed down perfectly why the syntax you wrote doesn't work.
Here are the syntaxes that do work for what you're probably trying to do:

---

If you want all 4 x 4 combinations for x and y, you want 2 nested loops:

```
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        print x, y
```

Or if you really want to use one loop:

```
import itertools
for (x, y) in itertools.product(range(4), range(4)):
    print x, y
```

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) generates all possible combinations:

[image]

This is less readable than 2 loops in this simple case, but the itertools module has many other powerful functions and is worth knowing...

---

If you want `x` and `y` to advance in parallel over two sequences (aka "lock-step" iteration):

```
for (x, y) in zip(range(4), range(4)):
    print x, y
# `zip(range(4), range(4))` is silly since you get x == y;
# would be useful for different sequences, e.g.
# zip(range(4), 'abcd')
```

[Background: The name `zip` comes from Haskell; think about how a Zipper takes one tooth from here and one from there:
[image: link text]

`zip()` cuts off to the length of the shortest sequence; the itertools module has other variants...]

Comment: `zip(range(4), range(4))` is rather useless example ;)

Comment: I know how zip works. Thanks. I'm not a total noob just because SilentGhost tagged the question 'beginner'

Comment: BandGap: How would we know? I think this is a good answer, he obviously took his time to help.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to sound condescending, just believe that self-contained explanations are better on average.  Also, people that might google the question *would* be python noobs in some cases.  [And put the pictures in becase I really like the zipper animation; I now dream of building some animated programming reference...]